# Why is it "der Mond"?

Tags: noun, gender, article

According to the rules of nouns in German language,

*der* is used for masculine nouns,
*die* is used for femenine nouns,
and *das* is used for neuters nouns.

*Mond* (*Moon*) is a neuter noun. So, it should be *das Mond* according to the rules. But, *der Mond* is used usually.

What is the reason for this usage?

Comment: Because it's masculine. What makes you think it were neuter?

Comment: Unfortunately, you are wrong. "Der Mond" is masculine.

Comment: Here the link to Duden: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mond

Comment: Possibly you think that there is a rule that words for inanimate objects are neuter in German. There is no such rule.

Comment: @IQV Why Mond is masculine ?

Comment: @Em1 Moon is an object. It can't be either masculine or femenine.

Comment: I can't tell you, why "Mond" is masculine. It **is** masculine, by definition, history - I don't know. Your have to learn the gender of nouns, that's so in many languages.

Comment: @NSiri refutation by counterexample: Der Salat, die Uhr, der Stift, die Tastatur, der Bildschirm, die Taste, ...........

Comment: @NSiri "Things" (don't use "objects", it's reserved for a different meaning in grammar) are not neuter by default. In fact, it doesn't matter if it's a thing or a person, if it's animate or inanimate. German grammar doesn't care about that.

Comment: I'm not really sure how you determined that r Mond should be s Mond, but it is indeed masculine.

Comment: @ss109 and all comenters, May be it is my culture. We never give a masculine or femenine to any things(inanimate) while writing/speaking usually. But, Some objects got either masculine or femenine in poem and some panegyrical things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question presupposes that *masculine*, *feminine* and *neuter* refer to the sex of whatever you're talking about. However, they do not. They refer to the grammatical gender of whatever you're talking about, and the grammatical gender of words only very very roughly corresponds to real-life sex. Or, as Mark Twain put it: "In German, a young lady has no sex, while a turnip has." Many, many inanimate objects are masculine or feminine in German.

Thus, the moon in German is masculine.

(Also, moon and sun do have a gender even in English at times; in a poem you might refer to the sun as "he" and the moon as "she".)

Comment: +1 for Mark Twain.

Comment: I can only recommend reading [The Awful German Language](http://www.kombu.de/twain-2.htm) to anyone who thinks that gender is confusing and/or silly.

Comment: In other languages (Frensh, Portuguese...), it's the other way round: The sun is masculine and the moon is feminine.

Comment: Yes, and English started doing the French thing after the conquest, if I remember correctly, which is why you do the same in English (if you do it at all.) I remember I read once that typologically, southern languages often consider the sun as masculine and the moon as feminine and northern languages do it the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the real-world-*thing* that has a grammatical gender. It's the *word* that is used to name the thing. Often there are more than one words that you can use to name a thing. Let's take "car". This can be in German:

> Das Auto (neuter)
>   Der Wagen (male)
>   Die Karre (female)

»Auto« is the standard word for cars, »Wagen« is a little bit outdated and often used for some bigger limousines, and »Karre« is a shabby car. So if you have a rusty 15 years old limousine, you can use all three words. All three words can mean the very same automobile. But they have different genders.

Also note: A grammatical gender is a property of a language. It's not about biological gender. But if there is something that is biological male or female, then very often the grammatical gender is the same (take this as a rule of thumb, it's a quite safe rule). But there are exceptions:

Most famous exception is the German word for »girl« (a female human, between newborn and about 20 years old). You might think it had to be a female word, but it is not. The German word for »girl« is:

> Das Mädchen (neuter)

The reason for this exception is, that »Mädchen« is a diminutive, and all diminutives are always neuter. (This is a hard rule with no exceptions. So it's a stronger rule than the sex=gender-rule which is only a rule of thumb.) (»Mädchen« a diminutive of »die Maid« which is female, but »Maid« is outdated and no longer used in a normal conversation)

Other exceptions:

> Das Weib (neuter) (outdated word for »woman« or »wife«)
>   Die Tunte (female) (a la-di-da gay man)
>   Das Kind (neuter) (»child«, used for both biological genders)
>   Das Baby (neuter) (»baby«, used for both biological genders)

---

You better stop thinking of a »gender« of a word. Think of it as a »noun class«, because this is what it really is. It is just a grammatical property of nouns.

English has only one noun class, i.e. all Englisch nouns belong to the same noun class, and this class has no name. Italian has two noun classes, their names are "male" and "female". Swedish also has two noun classes, but the are not "male" and "female", but "utrum" and "neuter". German has tree noun classes, which are "male", "female" and "neuter". And the African language Swahili has 22 noun classes.